# How to create a default function that uses a specified associated type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

```rust
pub trait Builder<W: Write> {
    type Error: Error;

    fn build<'re>(
        writer: W,
        records: impl Iterator<Item = &'re Record>,
    ) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        let mut state = Self::create(writer)?;
        for record in records {
            state.next(record)?;
        }

        state.finalize()
    }

    fn build_string<'re>(
        records: impl Iterator<Item = &'re Record>,
    ) -> Result<String, <Self as Builder<&'??? mut Vec<u8>>>::Error> { // what type should I use?
        let mut buffer = Vec::new();
        Self::<???>::build(&mut buffer, records)?; // same question
        Ok(String::from_utf8_lossy(buffer.as_slice()).to_string())
    }

    fn create(writer: W) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>;
    fn next(&mut self, record: &Record) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
    fn finalize(&mut self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}
```

As far as I understand, it's not possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here. If that's correct, then what is the preferable way to implement default `build_string` method, so that I can access it on types that implement `Builder`?

Comment: The only associated type is `Error` did you mean the type parameter `W: Write`? You can refer to it by it's name: `W`, though it's unclear to me why it needs to be a parameter of the trait instead of on the functions.

Comment: A `Builder<W: Write>` implementation for some `W` does not guarantee a `Builder<&mut Vec<u8>>` implementation so `Self as Builder<&mut Vec<u8>` might simply not exist and there is no way to know for your default functions.

Comment: @cafce25 all implementations of the trait use writer as an internal field. do I get rid of it?

Comment: @cafce25 is it possible to add some kind of constraint so `build_string` would be available only if `Builder<&mut Vec<u8>` is constructible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```rust
pub trait Builder<W: Write>: Sized {
    type Error: std::error::Error;

    fn build<'re>(writer: W, records: impl Iterator<Item = &'re Record>) -> Result<W, Self::Error> {
        let mut state = Self::create(writer)?;
        for record in records {
            state.next(record)?;
        }

        state.finalize()
    }

    fn create(writer: W) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>;
    fn next(&mut self, record: &Record) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
    fn finalize(self) -> Result<W, Self::Error>;
}

pub trait BuilderString: Builder<Vec<u8>> {
    fn build_string<'re>(records: impl Iterator<Item = &'re Record>) -> Result<String, Self::Error>;
}

impl<T> BuilderString for T
where
    T: Builder<Vec<u8>>,
{
    fn build_string<'re>(records: impl Iterator<Item = &'re Record>) -> Result<String, Self::Error> {
        let buffer = Vec::new();
        let buffer = Self::build(buffer, records)?;
        Ok(String::from_utf8_lossy(buffer.as_slice()).to_string())
    }
}
```

Thanks to Seaish on Rust Programming Language Discord server.